# Troubleshooting input device detection in Windows Xp Pro Sp3

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, keyboard, boot, mouse

My laptop (Acer travelmate 4152NlCi)doesn't respond to the keyboard and mouse anymore while booting in Windows Xp Pro Sp3. i can't type the password and login. I have Opensuse 11.0 on it as well and it works. So I can boot into Linux and not Windows, not even in safe mode. What would be the troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try using a USB keyboard and mouse.  Plug them in when Windows is on the logon screen and wait about 30 seconds for the new devices to be installed.  If that lets you log in, then you can check Device Manager and see if your built-in components are even being detected.

If that doesn't work, you can try using Remote Desktop to connect to the computer once it boots up.  If you don't have Remote Desktop turned on, you can try [using PsExec to enable Remote Desktop from a second computer](http://thebackroomtech.com/2007/05/18/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-xp-machine-remotely/).  Once you've connected via Remote Desktop, you should be able to check why the local machine isn't accepting input.

If you can't get Remote Desktop started, you can try using a VNC tool like [Fastpush](http://www.darkage.co.uk/) to start a VNC server on the problem computer, then connect that way.

Comment: it doesn't detect an external keyboard or USB mouse. I'll try the remote Desktop way